# Importing Foundation and jQuery into nextjs web application

Tags: jquery, typescript, zurb-foundation, next.js

I am trying to import Zurb Foundation's scripts into my next js application only I receive the following error when including Foundation core...

> /Users/alasdair_macrae/Sites/merlin/spa_runescape/node_modules/foundation-sites/js/foundation.core.js:3
>
> import $ from 'jquery';
>
> ^^^^^^
>
> SyntaxError: Cannot use import statement outside a module

I am trying to import it on a Layout Component as follows...

```
import $ from "jquery";
import {Foundation} from 'foundation-sites/js/foundation.core.js'
Foundation.addToJquery($);
import {Triggers} from 'foundation-sites/js/foundation.util.triggers'
Triggers.init($, Foundation);
// Components
import Header from "../../components/Header";
import Footer from "../../components/Footer";

/**
 * Default layout for pages containing a header and footer
 * @param props
 * @constructor
 */
const DefaultLayout = (props) => {
    useEffect(() => {
        console.log($);
    }, []);

    return (
        <>
            <Head>
                <title>{props.pageTitle}</title>
            </Head>
            <Header />
            {props.children}
            <Footer />
        </>
    )
};

export default DefaultLayout;
```

(very similar to [this suggested solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59498327/importing-foundation-js-package-inside-next-project) however no matter how I alter the names of the import I receive the same error).

Comment: importcan be only used in ES6 projects and by using the correct parser like babel.

Answer (score 0):

Never mind - realised I was not using the dist of Foundation.

I was importing the source code.

(fail)